Monitoring asyncio ready queue in python
I'm optimizing the performance of a Python application that includes many non-blocking I/O operations, some of which involve making HTTP API calls. We use an asynchronous client for all I/O operations, including database and Redis access. During load testing with concurrent users, we've noticed that processing times significantly increase with the number of users. How can we determine if this slowdown is due to delays in API calls or if there is a significant delay in the event loop picking up tasks that have been resolved and added to the ready queue?
I have tried setting up an async task which runs continuously with an asyncio.sleep(2) and measures the time difference between the actual time and 2 seconds, thus giving me a proxy of what is the delay at that moment. This worked fine even though with some overhead of running a task every 2 seconds and it's still a proxy. Instead, I'm looking for ways to monitor this on explicit async tasks.

What is the "ready queue"? There isn't such a concept in asyncio, as far as I know. Do you have a queue that you are managing yourself? I'm also not sure what you mean in general by "significant delay in the event loop picking up tasks that have been resolved and added to the ready queue". Is your timing of the asyncio.sleep(2) task always returning close to two seconds as you increase the number of users? If it isn't, then it's possible that a library you are using has a synchronous call that is blocking the asyncio event loop thread.

I think that in general this needs more information. How many calls are you making out? How many servers and connections are coming in? Can you list the various I/O libraries that you are using? What "processing times" are you measuring?
